# KVM API usage in C: How can I enable KVM_CAP_SYNC_MMU?

Tags: c, linux, kvm

I would like to learn more about KVM, so I've started to write my very primitive and crude "PC emulator" in C using the KVM API on Linux (x86_64). However I've encountered a problem. I'm using HLT opcode as a "trap" to escape from kvm run, so I can emulate there what I want, even modifying the VM's memory space I mmap()'ed. Then I discovered, the changes made into the memory region assigned to the VM is "not seen" by the "guest" inside the VM. As far as I understand, I would need KVM_CAP_SYNC_MMU.

Here is the problem, that I cannot find any examples on the net, how to do this. By try-and-error, I came up with this solution:

```
kvm.kvm_run = mmap(NULL, vcpu_mmap_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, kvm.vcpu_fd, 0);
if (kvm.kvm_run == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("KVM: mmap kvm_run");
    return -1;
}          
struct kvm_enable_cap caps;
memset(&caps, 0, sizeof(caps));
caps.cap = KVM_CAP_SYNC_MMU;
if (ioctl(kvm.vcpu_fd, KVM_ENABLE_CAP, &caps) < 0)
    perror("KVM: KVM_ENABLE_CAP");
    return -1;
}
```

However this always gives me: `KVM: KVM_ENABLE_CAP: Invalid argument`. Without this `KVM_ENABLE_CAP` everything works (to the point that there is no error), however my whole project pointless then, since the guest cannot see the changes I'm making in the HLT "trap handler". Does anybody has some idea what mistake I have here?

Answer (score 0):

`KVM_CAP_SYNC_MMU` does not need to be enabled (and in fact cannot be enabled). You can simply query whether it is available or not via `KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION`.